# Find the limit or prove that the limit does not exist $\lim_{x\to c}\sqrt{x} $ for $c\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis

$\lim_{x\to c}\sqrt{x} $ for $c\geq 0$

I know that ... limit exists and it is $\sqrt{c}$

However, my professor want me to give rigorous proof.

I tried to use

$0<\mid x - c \mid < \delta$  $(x \in R)$

$\mid \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{c} \mid < \epsilon $

But I don't know what I have to put for $\delta $ and how can I transform $\mid \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{c} \mid$ to $\mid x - c \mid$

Comment: hint: $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}| = \frac{|x-c|}{|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}|}$

Comment: ah .. so I can put $\mid \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{c} \mid \epsilon $ into $\delta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to analyze two cases.  For the first case, we take $c=0$.  For the second case, we take $c>0$.

---

**CASE: $1$: $\displaystyle c=0$**

We assume that the limit is taken within the domain of definition of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.  Then, give $\epsilon>0$

$$\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{0}\right|<\epsilon$$

whenever, $0<x<\delta=\epsilon^2$.

---

**CASE: $2$: $\displaystyle c>0$**

We first restrict $\delta <c/2$.  Then, with $x\in [c/2,3c/2]$ we have for any given $\epsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}\right|&=\frac{|x-c|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}\\\\
&\le \frac{|x-c|}{\sqrt{c/2}+\sqrt{c}}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{2}{(2+\sqrt{2})\sqrt{c}}\right)\,|x-c|\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever, $|x-c|<\delta=\min\left(c/2,\left(1+\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right)\epsilon\right)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. How do you find $\delta < c/2$ ????

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The choice to restrict $\delta$ is arbitrary.  We just want to pin it down so that $x>c-\delta>0$.  So any value less than $c$ suffices.